# What are the risks of opening ports (and how do I protect against said risks)

Tags: port-forwarding

I started a minecraft server and I want to have it running 24/7 with open ports so that friends can play. My dad thinks that we will be hacked because of the open ports, and I have hardly any knowledge of networking and such. So can anyone tell me the risks and how to prevent said risks like I'm five years old? Thanks!

Comment: Hey I see the other post but nobody explains it easily, I was hoping for a better explanation